# How do Russian speakers say "like a stump"?

Tags: перевод

Looking back on a time when we ran into what briefly seemed like a bear in the woods, I wanted to say something in Russian to the effect of our finding ourselves fear-struck and helplessly "riveted to the spot", as we say "like a stump (of a tree)" in English.

In Russian, is it more like:

> стоять **как столб**
>
> than: стоять **как пень**

I'm also wondering if the usage of "как столб/пень" can extend to instances where you cannot tear/pull yourself away from the TV etc, as if to be rooted in front of them, only because you are completely **engrossed** in that activity?

Can "как столб/пень" be used to convey the idea of being riveted to the TV screen etc of your own accord, as opposed to fear-induced temporary *paralysis*? Or in the case of such *voluntary* immobility, would you use some other expression?

Answer (score 5):

**как пень** usually refers to sitting, that is **сидеть как пень** in  statements disapproving of lack of activity, e.g.

> *Сидит* целыми днями у телевизора/за компьютером *как (тот) пень*

**как столб** is also a disapproving comparison referring to someone else's immovability which creates obstacles

> *Стал как столб* в проходе и ни тебе ни пройти, ни проехать <sup>*very colloquial*</sup>

In this sense **как вкопанный** (as if dug in) is used as well, but it also fits in the context of having to stop dead in one's tracks because of a startling event or sudden emergence of an obstacle

> Меня заворожил протяжный шум лесных верхушек, и я *остановился как
> вкопанный* на дорожке
>
> Перед самым барьером конь *остановился как вкопанный*

In the context of immobile or lifeless laying the comparison is with a log - **лежать как бревно**

Comment: Basically, one of them is higher, hence the difference in usage. And `Остолбенеть от ужаса` should be considered a special case since you can `стоять как стоб` for other reasons, like great surprise.

Comment: fear-struck also can be оцепенеть

Comment: @ddbug must too have something to do with пень - оце-пенеть ))))

Answer (score 2):

**Остолбенеть** от ужаса (страха, неожиданности и т. п.). Literally, to become immovable like a pole (столб).

Answer (score 2):

**Остолбенеть** (to be stunned) is a verb, then there's an idiom **«на него столбняк (tetanus) нашел»**.

For a voluntary action there's **«не мог оторваться от телевизора»**.

Comment: "Остолбенеть" is good when immobility is caused by an event that is more surprising than threatening. For fear-struck people, "замереть" ("turn still like a dead") or "окаменеть" ("get petrified") is more appropriate.